# Show div on option selected is not working

Tags: jquery

I want to:

- show the div with the class ".div" when the option with id "showDiv" is selected, and
- hide again when is not selected.

My code is not working.

**Question:** Do you know where is the issue?

```js
$('#showDiv').bind('change',function(e){
  event.preventDefault()
  $('.div').show("slow");
});
```

```css
.div{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Select</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
        <option selected class="selected">Option 1</option>
        <option id="showDiv">Option 2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row div">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputName">Email</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`change` **Event** works on `<select>`, not on `<option>` elements

```js
$('#exampleFormControlSelect1').on('change', function() {

    $(".div").toggle( $("#showDiv").is(":selected") );

});
```

```css
.div{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Select</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
        <option selected class="selected">Option 1</option>
        <option id="showDiv">Option 2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row div">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputName" class="text-heading h6 font-weight-semi-bold">Email</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```